# How to convert a data.frame (already loaded into R) into R script commands which will create it, data incldued?

Tags: r

I have data stored in a spreadsheet. I import this into R as a data.frame called df. 
In the R console the data.frame df looks like:

```
> df
         Major    Flavor Test
1     Business   vanilla 77.0
2     Business chocolate 77.3
3  LiberalArts chocolate 75.7
.
.
26        STEM chocolate 91.1
```

Question and what I want to do.

I want to send my students an R script with the data from the above data frame explicitly in the script itself.

Yes, I know it is better to separate the data and the script, but I don't want to do it that way. I want the data in the script itself.

I know how to do this by brute force, I can type everything, into the R script, e.g.:

```
dfB <- data.frame("Major" = c("Business", "Business", "LiberalArts"), 
                "Flavor" = c("chocolate", "vanilla","vanilla"), 
                "Test" = c(77.7, 82.6, 80.6)
                )
```

which will work, but will take a while to type.

But, I think there should be an easier way to do this.

There should be a fairly easy way to have R output the data from
the data.frame df to either the R console or to a text file, which I can
then just copy and paste into the R script. There should be a function
called something like data.frame.inverse, which takes an R data.frame with data in it, and output the R commands to create it.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `dput(df)` so you get the structure

Comment: ...and then you can send `dfB <- [that output]

Comment: Thanks LocoGirls and Jon Spring for solving the problem.